not able to connect to kafka broker using java sdk
I have created a kafka topic with one partitions and no replication on my localhost , tested message transmission through kafka console consumer and console producer and it worked fine but while trying to send message through java sdk client using the following code The message is getting timed out and I cant see it on console consumer which is consuming on the same topic . Is there any change in properties reuired?
Properties properties =new Properties();
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092");
properties.setProperty("key.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("value.serializer", StringSerializer.class.getName());
properties.setProperty("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
properties.setProperty("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
KafkaProducer<String,String> producer =new KafkaProducer<String, String>(properties);
ProducerRecord <String,String> producerRecord = new ProducerRecord<>("one","hello abhishek");
producer.send(producerRecord);


A producer doesn't need any deserializer... Please clarify how you're running Kafka

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.


The message is getting timed out

Kafka sends data in a batch, after a flush interval or when a batch.size amount of bytes are sent
If you send less, you must call producer.flush()
